# Visual Studio: Sql Server in-project DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I would like to create a new VisualStudio project with a simple SQL server db, but i want it to be portable, because several people will need to have access to the DB.

**So it should be also accessible from a user with password.**

The point is that when i create a Local SQL server DB i can't create a new user because it sais `You can only create a user with password in a contained DB`.

Is there a way to create a Local DB with password or a way to let several user access to the same DB?

Thx

Comment: If you want all users to access the same database, you need to have a database server of some sort.  The connection string is then configured in the application.

Comment: @Jason actually it's not such trivial to buy a SQL server to let the other developers accessing the DB, or leaving my domestic dual core alone around in the net when i'm out of home

Comment: SQL Server Express is free (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) if you don't have access to the developer edition, and every developer can install it themselves, then all you would need is have some shared mechanism to lay out the db schema, etc as you would with any db.  Not to nick pick, but about leaving your dual core at home alone, you asked how to let several users access the same db  :)

Comment: @Jason but what about the data? How could i make it available for all users?

Comment: there are ways around the data problem, but that was not what was asked, was it?  The question was `Is there a way to create a Local DB with password or a way to let several user access to the same DB?` which is (without a lot of probably unnecessary work and hack) you can't without installing a shared instance of SQL Server (or some other DBMS), which is what I am suggesting you *can* do, and it's free  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a Local DB with password

Yes. I'd recommend using Sql Server CE or SqlLite for a database like this. If you're only using Sql Server as a data store on the local machine, Sql Server, even Express Edition, which is still the full Sql Server engine, is usually *way* overkill for this. The full Sql Server engine really only makes sense when the database engine is the sole, *exclusive* reason that the machine where it runs exists.

> Is there... a way to let several user access to the same DB?

Yes. Install Sql Server on a dedicated database machine, instead of using a Local DB, and set the appropriate connection string and permissions.

Here's the trick: **you can't do both**, at least not without going through all the same trouble you'd go through setting up a real Sql Server to run on the machine where this will be installed.

Comment: `Here's the trick: you can't do both` That's the  answer i wanted. THX!